# to read file and compare column in python

Tags: python

for example:
consider the contents of file1.txt:

``````````````````````````````````````````
1   0   9227    1152    34  2
2   111 7622    1120    34  2
3   68486   710 1024    14  2
6   265065  3389    800 22  2
7   393152  48438   64  132 3
8   412251  46744   64  132 3
9   430593  50866   256 95  4
10  430730  10770   256 95  4
11  433750  12701   256 14  3
12  437926  2794    64  34  2
13  440070  43  32  96  3
14  440102  44  32  96  3
15  440357  43  32  96  3
16  440545  43  32  96  3
17  440599  43  32  96  3
18  440625  43  32  96  3
19  440999  84  32  96  0
20  441574  44  32  96  3
`````````````````````````````````````````
`````````````````````````````````````````
`````````````````````````````````````````
`````````````````````````````````````````
`````````````````````````````````````````
`````````````````````````````````````````
``````````````````````````````````````````

which the contains `n` jobs with `6` fields(i,e column(0-5))

Now, for example, I take the first 19 jobs as history. Then I need to start reading from the 20th and so on comparing the columns `3,4,5` which matches with the above jobs in the history.
if it does as in the example where the 20th job matches with 6(13,14,15,16,17,18) 6 jobs in the history
now i need to create a list of those matching jobs containing only column2?.

Can any one suggest a code in python by which its possible for me to read the 20st line and compare with the above history and continue to `21,22,23------------------` until the end of the file is reached......

Comment: Please format your code/ text file.

Comment: @SwethaH please, could you clarify what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: oh I get it, the column counts start from zero.   Most confusing explaination.  Where is your attempt at a script?

Comment: You read 20 lines, store them, read the next 20 lines, compare, read the next 20 lines, compare etc etc. Which part are you stuck on? [What have you got so far](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)?

Answer (score 2):

Check if this works for you:

```
>>> history = {}
>>> historycount = 17
>>> for line in open("filename"):
    job = line.split()
    jobmatch_criteria = '-'.join(job[-3:])
    if historycount > 0:
        history.setdefault(jobmatch_criteria,[]).append(job)
        historycount -= 1
    else:
        print "Job", job[0], "Matched with:", '\n\t'.join(' '.join(i) for i in history[jobmatch_criteria]) if jobmatch_criteria in history else "None"


Job 20 Matched with: 13 440070 43 32 96 3
    14 440102 44 32 96 3
    15 440357 43 32 96 3
    16 440545 43 32 96 3
    17 440599 43 32 96 3
    18 440625 43 32 96 3
Job 21 Matched with: 6 265065 3389 800 22 2
```

I used this as test data:

```
1   0   9227    1152    34  2
2   111 7622    1120    34  2
3   68486   710 1024    14  2
6   265065  3389    800 22  2
7   393152  48438   64  132 3
8   412251  46744   64  132 3
9   430593  50866   256 95  4
10  430730  10770   256 95  4
11  433750  12701   256 14  3
12  437926  2794    64  34  2
13  440070  43  32  96  3
14  440102  44  32  96  3
15  440357  43  32  96  3
16  440545  43  32  96  3
17  440599  43  32  96  3
18  440625  43  32  96  3
19  440999  84  32  96  0
20  441574  44  32  96  3
21  265065  3389    800 22  2
```

Comment: Upvoted!! This looks more pythonic than my solution. Thanks :)

Comment: @mshsayem thanks but the history is not of fixed length for the 22nd job the history will be 21 & for 23rd job the history will be 24th and so on....plz tell me how i can do that.....

Comment: Update the `history` dictionary as necessary